# Always disable status bar and bottom bar in a custom launcher

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-statusbar, android-bottomnav

I need to write custom android launcher with only one my application and with disabling android system statusbar and bottom bar. Here is my code

in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

in `styles.xml`

```
 <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

ins `MainActivity.class`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        hideSystemUi()
        buttonStartMyApp.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Start own app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

private fun hideSystemUi() {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
    }
```

This launcher starts with only one button (its okay) and without status bar and bottom nav bar. BUT we can to get them with top-down swipe on the top of the screen. How to disable this function? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have implemented the `IMMERSIVE_STICKY` flag which allows the status bar to be called by top-down swipe on the top of the screen. To disable this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY);
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

To disable status drop down, use this method. This is an overlay over status bar and consumed all input events. It prevents the status from expanding.

**Note:**

`customViewGroup` is custom class which extends any layout(frame,relative layout etc) and consumes touch event.
To consume touch event override the onInterceptTouchEvent method of the view group and return true.

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

**customViewGroup implementation**

```
WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

            // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |

            // Draws over status bar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    localLayoutParams.height = (int) (50 * getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

    customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(this);

    manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
```

Comment: The 'customViewGroup implementation' crashes on API 24+

Answer (score 1):

Run a Service in background and just close the status bar always. For Oreo and above this is the only one solution I have found. For below versions we can use the above answer.

```
package your.package;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class ServiceCloseBar extends Service {

    private static Timer timer;
    private static TimerTask task;
    private static int TIME_INTERVAL=100;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try {
            timer=new Timer();
            task = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Object sbservice = getSystemService( "statusbar" );
                        Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
                        Method expandMethod;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
                            expandMethod = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
                        } else {
                            expandMethod = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                        }
                        expandMethod .invoke( sbservice );  
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    };
                }
            };

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, TIME_INTERVAL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```