# how to show status bar icons in kiosk mode android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kiosk

I am working on an android app in kiosk mode (app starts on system boot), lock screen but I want my status bar to be visible(battery status, wifi status, time)

Comment: How are you entering Kiosk mode?

Comment: by making my app as home app and device admin

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668610/always-disable-status-bar-and-bottom-bar-in-a-custom-launcher?